# Weird behaviour of row class in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

Today, I'm facing a weird issue in form designing. I'm using bootstrap 3 and in my HTML code I've assigned `row` class to various divs. Issue I'm facing is two divs having same class are behaving differently.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frmcreatebank" role="form">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-6 form-group-sm">
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
                <label class="col-sm-5" for="BANKROUTENO">
                      BANKROUTE NO :
                </label>
            <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
                      @Html.TextBox("TXT_BANKROUTENO", null, null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required] minSize[9] number", maxLength = 9, data_width = "100%" })
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-6 form-group-sm">
      <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
          <label class="col col-sm-5" for="BANKNAME">
                BANK NAME :
          </label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
      <div class="form-group">
          @Html.TextBox("TXT_BANKNAME", null, null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required]", maxLength = 50 })
      </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
            <label class="col col-sm-5" for="ADD1">
                  ADDRESS(1) :
            </label>
        <div class="col col-sm-7">
            @Html.TextBox("TXT_ADD1", null, null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required]", maxLength = 50 })
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
         <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
             <label for="ADD2" class="col col-sm-5">
                  ADDRESS(2) :
             </label>
         <div class="col col-sm-7">
             @Html.TextBox("TXT_ADD2", null, null, new { @class = "form-control", maxLength = 50 })
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
         <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
             <label class="col col-sm-5" for="ADD3">
                   ADDRESS(3) :
             </label>
         <div class="col col-sm-7">
             @Html.TextBox("TXT_ADD3", null, null, new { @class = "form-control", maxLength = 50 })
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
                <label class="col col-sm-5" for="PINCODE">
                     PINCODE :
                </label>
            <div class="col col-sm-7">
                @Html.TextBox("TXT_PINCODE", null, null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required] minSize[6] number", maxLength = 6 })
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col col-sm-5" for="CITY">CITY :</label>
          <div class="col col-sm-7">
             @Html.DropDownList("DDL_CITY", new SelectList(ViewBag.TypeList, "CODE", "LONGDESC"), "-- Select City --", new { @class = "selectpicker validate[required]", data_width = "100%" })
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
       <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
           <label class="col col-sm-5" for="EMAIL">
                 EMAIL :
           </label>
        <div class="col col-sm-7">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBox("TXT_EMAIL", null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required,custom[email]]" })
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
       <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
           <label class="col col-sm-5" for="TELEPHONE1">
                 TELEPHONE(1) :
           </label>
       <div class="col col-sm-7">
           <div class="form-group">
              @Html.TextBox("TXT_TELEPHONE1", null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required] number", maxLength = 12 })
           </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
         <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
             <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
                 <label class="col col-sm-5" for="TELEPHONE2">
                       TELEPHONE(2) :
                 </label>
              <div class="col col-sm-7">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      @Html.TextBox("TXT_TELEPHONE2", null, new { @class = "form-control number", maxLength = 12 })
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
      <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
          <label class="col col-sm-5" for="MOBILE">
                MOBILE :
          </label>
       <div class="col col-sm-7">
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.TextBox("TXT_MOBILE", null, new { @class = "form-control number", maxLength = 10 })
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Issue here is there is a lot of gap between two rows.

Problem is stated in this screenshot.[image]

Here as you can see there is too much gap between first row and second row. I want this gap to be same as gap between second row and third row.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure have you looked you code and compare first row with second/third or not. There is a clearly difference between first row and second row.

For example, you have used `form-group` with BANKROUTE NO : input and complete div wrapped around BANK NAME : input with `form-group`. Just need to remove those two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```html
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmcreatebank" role="form">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-6 form-group-sm">
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
                <label class="col-sm-5" for="BANKROUTENO">
                      BANKROUTE NO :
                </label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                      @Html.TextBox("TXT_BANKROUTENO", null, null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required] minSize[9] number", maxLength = 9, data_width = "100%" })
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-6 form-group-sm">
              <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
                  <label class="col col-sm-5" for="BANKNAME">
                        BANK NAME :
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-7">
                      @Html.TextBox("TXT_BANKNAME", null, null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required]", maxLength = 50 })
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
            <label class="col col-sm-5" for="ADD1">
                  ADDRESS(1) :
            </label>
            <div class="col col-sm-7">
                @Html.TextBox("TXT_ADD1", null, null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required]", maxLength = 50 })
            </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
         <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
             <label for="ADD2" class="col col-sm-5">
                  ADDRESS(2) :
             </label>
             <div class="col col-sm-7">
                 @Html.TextBox("TXT_ADD2", null, null, new { @class = "form-control", maxLength = 50 })
             </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
         <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
             <label class="col col-sm-5" for="ADD3">
                   ADDRESS(3) :
             </label>
             <div class="col col-sm-7">
                 @Html.TextBox("TXT_ADD3", null, null, new { @class = "form-control", maxLength = 50 })
             </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
                <label class="col col-sm-5" for="PINCODE">
                     PINCODE :
                </label>
                <div class="col col-sm-7">
                    @Html.TextBox("TXT_PINCODE", null, null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required] minSize[6] number", maxLength = 6 })
                </div>
        </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col col-sm-5" for="CITY">CITY :</label>
              <div class="col col-sm-7">
                 @Html.DropDownList("DDL_CITY", new SelectList(ViewBag.TypeList, "CODE", "LONGDESC"), "-- Select City --", new { @class = "selectpicker validate[required]", data_width = "100%" })
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
           <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
               <label class="col col-sm-5" for="EMAIL">
                     EMAIL :
               </label>
            <div class="col col-sm-7">
                @Html.TextBox("TXT_EMAIL", null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required,custom[email]]" })
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
           <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
               <label class="col col-sm-5" for="TELEPHONE1">
                     TELEPHONE(1) :
               </label>
               <div class="col col-sm-7">
                   <div class="form-group">
                      @Html.TextBox("TXT_TELEPHONE1", null, new { @class = "form-control validate[required] number", maxLength = 12 })
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
         <div class="col col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
             <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
                 <label class="col col-sm-5" for="TELEPHONE2">
                       TELEPHONE(2) :
                 </label>
              <div class="col col-sm-7">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      @Html.TextBox("TXT_TELEPHONE2", null, new { @class = "form-control number", maxLength = 12 })
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 form-group-sm">
          <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
              <label class="col col-sm-5" for="MOBILE">
                    MOBILE :
              </label>
           <div class="col col-sm-7">
             <div class="form-group">
                 @Html.TextBox("TXT_MOBILE", null, new { @class = "form-control number", maxLength = 10 })
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</form>
```